# Duality of SISO control system

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, dual-spaces

I am recently learning state space representation of Single-Input Single-Output LTI system, by the book *Modern Control Engineering, 5th edition*.

Suppose a system is represented by a homogeneous transfer function $G(s)=\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}=\frac{b_0s^n+b_1s^{n-1}+...+b_{n-1}s+b_n}{s^n+a_1s^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}s+a_n}$, whose state space model(controllable canonical form) is illustrated in the following figure,
[image: CCF model]

where state variables are given by [image]

The system can also be interpreted into observable canonical form, as the figure follows,
[image]

and state variables respectively,

[image]

I have my own understanding (maybe wrong) of controllable canonical form, that the scalar $u(t)$ is inputted into the highest derivative of state variable, which drives the dynamics of the system. An observer (which is the numerator $N(s)$ of the transfer function) watches every order of derivatives and put a weight onto them, thus forms the output. The observer does not change the dynamics of the system. I noticed that the input of CCF goes through a cascaded train of with a serial of integrators while the output is parallel, but in OCF the output goes out from serial integrators and the input goes into every integrator parallelly.

I am looking for the duality of CCF and OCF, by the 'findings' above, I thought if I inverse the input and output of a CCF, the system turns into OCF, with sums (nodes) turns into separators, and separators turns into sums. Does this makes any sense? How could I understand the duality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let us start with the following representation of a SISO linear system with rational transfer function $H(s)$ and consider a minimal realization $(A,B,C,D)$, that is, $H(s)=C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D$. We can write the associated state-space system

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x}(t)&=&Ax(t)+Bu(t)\\
y(t)&=&Cx(t)+Du(t).
\end{array}
$$

Since $H(s)$ is a scalar, then have that $H(s)=H(s)^T$ and, therefore

$$H(s)=(C(sI-A)^{-1}B+D)^T=B^T(sI-A^T)^{-1}C^T+D^T.$$

This means that the following state-space system
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{\tilde x}(t)&=&A^T\tilde x(t)+C^Tu(t)\\
y(t)&=&B^T\tilde x(t)+D^T u(t).
\end{array}
$$
describes the same input-output relationship, but in a different state-space. Let us call that the *dual system*.

If we consider now the controllable canonical form $(A_c,B_c,C_c,D_c)$ and the observable canonical form $(A_o,B_o,C_o,D_o)$ as defined in your post, we can observe that

$$A_c=A_o^T,\ B_c=C_o^T,\ C_c=B_o^T,\ \textrm{and } D_c=D_o^T.$$

So, according to our definition, the controllable form is the dual of the observable form, and vice-versa.

That said, we can now look at your "flow interpretation". If you look closely, the fact of transposing and swapping the matrices have the following effect on the flow diagram:

- Arrows are reversed
- Sums become branching points
- Branching points become sums